# How to use reactjs to query and display content from webpage

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build an app with reactjs and I need to query information from a webpage. I am having a hard time finding any info online to help with my problem.

Edit: I figured it out, I need to use Jquery Ajax calls

A big thank you to Chris for helping me through this problem

Comment: React doesn't have any querying capabilities. You'd have to use something like jQuery (or even plain Ajax) to "query information from a webpage", then feed _that_ to React components.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `I need to query information from a webpage`?

Comment: I need to pull info from a webpage and display it on my app

Comment: @Rocket, yes I understand that. But can you be more specific? What kind of info? When does this info need to be pulled? etc

Comment: Here is the link https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime I do not know what type of data this is

Answer (score 0):

Without much information this is the best that comes to mind.

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html